# Issue while printing a hash of array in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to create a hash of array. Currently the array is of size 1 only.

```
$f1="/scratch/aime1/PerlCode/BeforeUpgrade.csv";
$f2="/scratch/aime1/PerlCode/AfterUpgrade.csv";
open(FIN, "< $f1");
while( $my_line = <FIN> )
{
    chomp $my_line;
    my @values = split(',', $my_line);
    my $key = shift @values;
    print "$key\n";     
    print "@values\n"; 
    $hash1{$key} = @values;

}
close(FIN);


for (keys %hash1) {
     my @value_array = $hash1{$_};
     print "Key is $_ and first Element of array is $value_array[0] \n";
}
```

So,the key is of the form `/scratch/aime1/idmUpgrade/idmUpgrade` and the value is its permission  i.e. `0755`

When I try to print this hash,output is:

```
Key is /scratch/aime1/idmUpgrade/idmUpgrade and first Element of array is 1
```

Array is always printed as 1 and not as 0755.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always include `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of EVERY perl script.

You're assigning an array to a hash key, to do that you need to take a reference.  Otherwise, you're just assigning the array count (which is 1)

```
$hash1{$key} = \@values;
```

Similarly, when you want to retrieve, it, you'll need to dereference it:

```
my @value_array = @{$hash1{$_}};
```